# Randomizing host name and mac address on boot

Tags: networking, bash, mac

I'm trying to set up a startup script to randomize my hostname and mac address on boot. Here is the script

http://pastebin.com/qatdtbVH

The random mac address is working fine, but the hostname doesn't change from what I had it set to when I first installed Ubuntu. I think it worked twice, but now it doesn't. Anybody know why that is?

Comment: try doing the ifup after the host name change.  If that doesn't help, where are you running the script?  init? (as you need root rights to change the host name)

Comment: I'm thinking there's an easier way to grab a random word from your dictionary, instead of randomly sorting the whole file... maybe pick a random line number. But, would leaving a blank or no hostname work? Probably no more conspicuous than a random dictionary word (unless your dictionary is common default host names (android-123456?)

Comment: is there any problem with assiging the hostname using `echo $RANDOM` Sure, you could get a duplicate, but you would need the track used numbers or strings to prevent that. alternatively, you could use something like the epoch of when you login, which wouldn't be random, but would never repeat itself.